# Find users that take up a combined total of 100GB or greater in local folders only

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed, grep

I have to write a script that searches through local folders only and sums the combined total space used of all users that exist in the passwd nis map and then returns all users together with their combined totals who take up => 100GB. I'd like it to be sorted by the greatest consumers to the least greatest. We have many terabytes of storage so it should only have to make one pass through the file system. It will search under /export/ws so it's not searching from / root on down.

I wrote a script in a test environment that looks through 4 different folders. There are four owners of files or folders fongs, madhavav, billsb, and prestonm. This script does more than what I'm asking for but what it does do is look for users who are taking up more than 1GB of disk space so I guess I could reuse some of it here:

i.e.., instead of what I have in the script below:

```
if [ `grep "$i" ./temp_files/size_list | awk '{print $2}'` -gt 1025 ]
```

I guess I could just do this:

```
if [ `grep "$i" ./temp_files/size_list | awk '{print $2}'` -gt 1025*100 ]
```

I am sure than I am creating too many temp files and it could be done much more efficiently but here's that script:

```
find ./test1 -xdev -ls | sort -nr | awk '{print $5, $7, $11}' | sed -e 's/root//g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' > ./temp_files/list1
find ./test2 -xdev -ls | sort -nr | awk '{print $5, $7, $11}' | sed -e 's/root//g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' > ./temp_files/list2
find ./test3 -xdev -ls | sort -nr | awk '{print $5, $7, $11}' | sed -e 's/root//g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' > ./temp_files/list3
find ./test4 -xdev -ls | sort -nr | awk '{print $5, $7, $11}' | sed -e 's/root//g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' > ./temp_files/list4
awk '{print $1}' ./temp_files/list1 | sort -u > ./temp_files/share1
awk '{print $1}' ./temp_files/list2 | sort -u > ./temp_files/share2
awk '{print $1}' ./temp_files/list3 | sort -u > ./temp_files/share3
awk '{print $1}' ./temp_files/list4 | sort -u > ./temp_files/share4
comm -12 ./temp_files/share1 ./temp_files/share2 > ./temp_files/list9
comm -12 ./temp_files/share1 ./temp_files/share3 >> ./temp_files/list9
comm -12 ./temp_files/share1 ./temp_files/share4 >> ./temp_files/list9
comm -12 ./temp_files/share2 ./temp_files/share3 >> ./temp_files/list9
comm -12 ./temp_files/share2 ./temp_files/share4 >> ./temp_files/list9
comm -12 ./temp_files/share3 ./temp_files/share4 >> ./temp_files/list9
sort -u ./temp_files/list9 > ./temp_files/list10
awk '{print $1, $3}' ./temp_files/list1 > ./temp_files/test1_all
awk '{print $1, $3}' ./temp_files/list2 > ./temp_files/test2_all
awk '{print $1, $3}' ./temp_files/list3 > ./temp_files/test3_all
awk '{print $1, $3}' ./temp_files/list4 > ./temp_files/test4_all
for i in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
grep $i ./temp_files/test1_all >> ./temp_files/"$i"_files_test1_all
done
for e in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
grep $e ./temp_files/test2_all >> ./temp_files/"$e"_files_test2_all
done
for d in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
grep $d ./temp_files/test3_all >> ./temp_files/"$d"_files_test3_all
done
for h in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
grep $h ./temp_files/test4_all >> ./temp_files/"$h"_files_test4_all
done
for f in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
subject="The UDU-ENG-SERVICES Team has found that you have files/folders in more than one share"
recipient=`getent passwd $f | awk -F":" '{ print $5 }'`
email=`/share/es-ops/scripts/adlookup.sh samid "$f" | awk '{print $2}'`
mail -s "$subject" "$email" << END_MAIL
Subject: $subject
Dear $recipient,

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
You have files/folders in more than one share:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share1:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test1_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share2:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test2_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share3:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test3_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share4:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test4_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..125}; echo`
Please merge your files together by `perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%a %b %e %Y",localtime(time()+ 3600*24*30);'` or the script will merge them for you.
`printf '%.0s-' {1..125}; echo`

Thanks,
UDU-ENG-SERVICES
END_MAIL
done
cat temp_files/test1_all | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u > temp_files/user_list
cat temp_files/test2_all | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u >> temp_files/user_list
cat temp_files/test3_all | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u >> temp_files/user_list
cat temp_files/test4_all | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u >> temp_files/user_list
sort -u temp_files/user_list > temp_files/user_list2
sed '/root/d' temp_files/user_list2 > temp_files/user_list3
for i in `cat temp_files/user_list3`
do
grep $i temp_files/list1 > temp_files/"$i"_files
done
for e in `cat temp_files/user_list3`
do
grep $e temp_files/list2 >> temp_files/"$e"_files
done
for f in `cat temp_files/user_list3`
do
grep $f temp_files/list3 >> temp_files/"$f"_files
done
for y in `cat temp_files/user_list3`
do
grep $y temp_files/list4 >> temp_files/"$y"_files
done
for c in `cat temp_files/user_list3`
do
cat temp_files/"$c"_files | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' > temp_files/"$c"_sum
done
for i in `cat ./temp_files/user_list3`
do
echo "$i"" "$((`cat ./temp_files/"$i"_sum`/1024/1024))" "MB >> ./temp_files/size_list
done
for i in `cat ./temp_files/size_list | awk '{print $1}'`
do
if [ `grep "$i" ./temp_files/size_list | awk '{print $2}'` -gt 1025 ]
then
echo `grep "$i" ./temp_files/size_list` >> ./temp_files/size_list2
fi
done
cat ./temp_files/size_list2 | awk '{print $1, $2/1024, "GB"}' > ./temp_files/size_list3
for i in `cat ./temp_files/size_list3 | awk '{print $1}'`
do
subject="The UDU-ENG-SERVICES Team has found that your files/folders are taking up more than 1024M of disk space"
recipient=`getent passwd $i | awk -F":" '{ print $5 }'`
email=`/share/es-ops/scripts/adlookup.sh samid "$i" | awk '{print $2}'`
mail -s "$subject" "$email" << END_MAIL
Subject: $subject
Dear $recipient,

`printf '%.0s-' {1..90}; echo`
You have exceeded the 1024M space allowance on our shares.
`printf '%.0s-' {1..90}; echo`

`grep "$i" ./temp_files/size_list3` 

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share1:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$i"_files_test1_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share2:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$i"_files_test2_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share3:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$i"_files_test3_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`
Below are some of the files you have in share4:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..65}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/"$i"_files_test4_all | head -10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..125}; echo`
Please reduce your space footprint by `perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%a %b %e %Y",localtime(time()+ 3600*24*30);'` or the script will do it for you.
`printf '%.0s-' {1..125}; echo`

Thanks,
UDU-ENG-SERVICES
END_MAIL
done
ypcat passwd | cut -d: -f1 > ./temp_files/valid_users
for i in `cat ./temp_files/user_list2`
do
if ! /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q "$i" ./temp_files/valid_users; then
    echo "$i" >> ./temp_files/invalid_users
fi
done
sort -u ./temp_files/invalid_users > ./temp_files/invalid_users2
if [[ -s ./temp_files/invalid_users2 ]] ; then
i=`awk '{ print $1 }' ./temp_files/invalid_users2`
mkdir ./cdarchive/"$i"
mv `cat ./temp_files/"$i"_files | awk '{print $3}' | awk '(NR == 1 || length < length(shortest)) { shortest = $0 } END { print shortest }'` ./cdarchive/"$i"
fi
for f in `cat ./temp_files/list10`
do
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "Below are some of the files $f has in share1" >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test1_all | head -10 >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "Below are some of the files $f has in share2" >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test2_all | head -10 >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "Below are some of the files $f has in share3" >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test3_all | head -10 >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "Below are some of the files $f has in share4" >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo `printf '%.0s-' {1..75}; echo` >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
cat ./temp_files/"$f"_files_test4_all | head -10 >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notifcation1
done
for g in `cat ./temp_files/invalid_users2`
do
echo -e `printf '%.0s-' {1..65}` >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "Invalid user $g's files were moved from:" >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo -e `printf '%.0s-' {1..65}` >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo `cat ./temp_files/"$g"_files | awk '{print $3}' | awk '(NR == 1 || length < length(shortest)) { shortest = $0 } END { print shortest }'` >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo -e `printf '%.0s-' {1..10}` >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "to:" >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo -e `printf '%.0s-' {1..10}` >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "                  " >> ./temp_files/notification2
echo "./cdarchive/$g" >> ./temp_files/notification2
done

subject="Workspace Report For Build Shares on 3par-nfs-05 `perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%a %b %e %Y",localtime(time()+ 3600*24*0);'`" 
recipient="UDU-ENG-SERVICES Team"
email="Brian.Bills@HP.Com"
mail -s "$subject" "$email" << END_MAIL
Subject: $subject
Dear $recipient,


`printf '%.0s-' {1..85}; echo`
The following users are using more than 1024MB of disk space:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..85}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/size_list3`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..85}; echo`
The following users have files/folders in more than one share:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..85}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/list10`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..45}; echo`
These are some of their shares:
`printf '%.0s-' {1..45}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/notifcation1`

`printf '%.0s-' {1..20}; echo`
Invalid Users
`printf '%.0s-' {1..20}; echo`

`cat ./temp_files/notification2`


Thanks,
UDU-ENG-SERVICES
END_MAIL
```

Comment: Maybe show us what you have tried. Maybe give 3-4 lines of sample output from your `niscat users` command? Maybe tell us your OS?

Comment: Consider using `quota`. Mount `/export/ws` with `usrquota` option, then `quotacheck` and `quotaon`

Answer (score 0):

use a `sort -n -k9` on the size columns number (`9` in the sample) of your compiled file